# Sim Missing Error - Huawei Embedded Modem(Model ME906s-158)

Tags: debian, huawei

I have a Lenovo thinkpad x260 with a Huawei Embedded Modem(Model ME906s-158). I've been using it with debian 9 sucessfully. Had need to move to Debian 10. Since the move, it stopped working. Tried a fresh install of Debian 9 but i can't still use the modem.

I keep seeing `"Modem couldn't be initialized: Couldn't check unlock status: SIM not inserted"` when i check the logs of ModemManager. I am also  so certain that there is a sim in the sim tray and it works on my mobile phone.

`mmcli -L`

```
Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.] HUAWEI Mobile
```

`mmcli -m 0`

```
/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 (device id 'ccd68b9767f3e72175547f52f29f8f5ef765317b')

Hardware |   manufacturer: 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.'
         |          model: 'HUAWEI Mobile'
         |       revision: '11.617.04.00.00'
         |   H/W revision: 'ML1ME906SM'
         |      supported: 'gsm-umts, lte'
         |        current: 'gsm-umts, lte'
         |   equipment id: 'XXX'
System   |         device: '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3'
         |        drivers: 'cdc_mbim, option1'
         |         plugin: 'Huawei'
         |   primary port: 'cdc-wdm0'
         |          ports: 'ttyUSB0 (at), cdc-wdm0 (mbim), wwp0s20f0u3c3 (net)'

Numbers  |           own : 'unknown'

Status   |           lock: 'unknown'
         | unlock retries: 'unknown'
         |          state: 'failed'
         |  failed reason: 'sim-missing'
         |    power state: 'on'
         |    access tech: 'unknown'
         | signal quality: '0' (cached)

Modes    |      supported: 'allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: none'
         |        current: 'allowed: any; preferred: none'

Bands    |      supported: 'unknown'
         |        current: 'unknown'

IP       |      supported: 'ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6'

SIM      |           path: 'none'

Bearers  |          paths: 'none'
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you solve it somehow?